# Can my portable radio receive amateur radio?

Tags: receiver

http://memorex-ce.com/product/amfm-pocket-radio/
Yeah, I guess it's cheap and probably won't pick it up but...

Comment: this is a product recommendation question in disguise, I think (your comment to the answer hints at that, too). Which is, I'm afraid, a bit off-topic here per our rules; but not all is lost: Maybe make this question more about which problem you're trying to solve!

Comment: Maybe it would be better to reformulate the question in such way as to ask for features a radio needs to have in order to be abke to receive amateur radio?

Comment: @MarcusMüller "Does this (kind of) product have this feature" is okay.

Comment: Uknow23:  that radio is quite specific to the AM and FM broadcast bands.  It will not receive shortwave bands.  However, if you do a simple search in Google or eBay or Amazon for "Shortwave radio receiver" you should be able to read the descriptions of radios that come up and get an idea of the difference.  The kind that you really want for amateur radio listening is a tad more expensive than plain shortwave radios.  I suggest you walk before you run.  Get a shortwave unit and see what you can hear.  Start with WWV at 5000 and 10000, then listen around 7000 to find international broadcasters.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though your pocket radio can pick up the FM broadcast band at 88-108 MHz and the AM broadcast band from 530-1700 kHz.  There aren't any ham bands in those ranges, so sorry, but your radio shouldn't be able to pick up amateur radio transmissions.

Comment: Do you know any portable pocket radios that can pick up those ranges, as well as normal am and fm?

Comment: yes, there are many available that do that, a popular brand is Sangean.

Comment: I own an Icom IC-R20 hand held receiver, its receive frequency range is 0.15 to 3304.999 MHz with cellular frequencies blocked.  Modes supported include:  LSB, USB, AM, CW, FM, WFM.  Great little radio, I use it as an emergency battery operated radio for that day when the 9.0 Earthquake happens in the northwest.  Pricey though, I think I paid about $595 new.